# failed to upload a table from sql file

Tags: mysql

Encountering

`Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /www/wwwroot/kopsis/config.php on line 95

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /www/wwwroot/kopsis/config.php on line 96

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /www/wwwroot/kopsis/config.php on line 97

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /www/wwwroot/kopsis/config.php on line 98

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'kopsis.akun' doesn't exist in /www/wwwroot/kopsis/config.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /www/wwwroot/kopsis/config.php(115): mysqli->prepare() #1 /www/wwwroot/kopsis/index.php(2): include('...') #2 {main} thrown in /www/wwwroot/kopsis/config.php on line 115`

This error occurs when running my code on a VPS with AAPanel. It works fine on cPanel hosting with PHP 7.4. How can I resolve this issue on the VPS with AAPanel and php 7.4 also?"

I've already switched to PHP 7.3, 8.1, and still encountering the same issue, even triggering new errors

This is Config.PHP code

oh sorry, this is my config.php code:

```php
<?php
// Menonaktifkan tampilan pesan kesalahan
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Atur zona waktu ke "Asia/Jakarta" (Waktu Indonesia Barat)
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
// Tampilkan tanggal dan waktu dalam format yang diinginkan
$currentDateTime = date('d M Y H:i:s');
// Memulai sesi
session_start();
// Mendefinisikan path fisik ke file connection.php
$path_to_connection = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].
"/connection.php";
// Melakukan include file menggunakan path fisik
include $path_to_connection;

// CEK LOGIN USER
if (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) {
  $key_login = $_COOKIE['login'];
  $ciphering = "AES-128-CTR";
  $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length($ciphering);
  $options = 0;
  $decryption_iv = '1234567891011121';
  $decryption_key = "ecommerce";
  $decryption = openssl_decrypt($key_login, $ciphering, $decryption_key, $options, $decryption_iv);
  $iduser_key_login = explode("hcCTZvFLD7XIchiaMqEka0TLzGgdpsXB", $decryption);
  $id_user_login = $iduser_key_login[0];
  $select_profile = $server - > prepare("SELECT * FROM `akun` WHERE `id`=?");
  $select_profile - > bind_param("i", $id_user_login);
  $select_profile - > execute();
  $result = $select_profile - > get_result();
  $profile = $result - > fetch_assoc();

  // Jika profil tidak ditemukan, redirect ke halaman logout
  if (!$profile) {
    header('Location: '.$url.
      '/system/logout.php');
    exit(); // Pastikan untuk menghentikan eksekusi setelah melakukan redirect
  }

  // Simpan informasi pemilik toko yang sedang login
  $iduser = $profile['id'];

  // COUNT CART
  $count_cart_header = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `keranjang` WHERE `id_user`='$iduser' ");
  $cek_cart_header = mysqli_num_rows($count_cart_header);
  // COUNT NOTIFICATION
  $count_notif_header = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `notification` WHERE `id_user`='$iduser' AND `status_notif`='' ");
  $cek_notif_header = mysqli_num_rows($count_notif_header);
  // COUNT FAVORIT
  $count_favorit_header = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `favorit` WHERE `user_id`='$iduser' ");
  $cek_favorit_header = mysqli_num_rows($count_favorit_header);
  // COUNT CHAT
  $count_chat_header = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `penerima_user_id`='$iduser' AND `status`='' ");
  $cek_chat_header = mysqli_num_rows($count_chat_header);
  // COUNT PESANAN
  $count_pesanan_header = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `invoice` WHERE `id_user`='$iduser' AND `tipe_progress`='' ");
  $cek_pesanan_header = mysqli_num_rows($count_pesanan_header);
}

// NOTIFIKASI JUMLAH PESAN BARU
$count_unread_chat = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `penerima_user_id`='1' AND `status`=''");
$cek_unread_chat = mysqli_num_rows($count_unread_chat);
// NOTIFIKASI JUMLAH PERMINTAAN PENARIKAN
$count_pending_rows = $server - > query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM `riwayat_penarikan` WHERE `status`=0");
$row = $count_pending_rows - > fetch_assoc();
$total_pending_rows = $row['total'];
// ADMIN MAIL
$setting_email_query = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `setting_email` WHERE `id`='1'");
$data_setting_email = mysqli_fetch_assoc($setting_email_query);
$setfrom_smtp = $data_setting_email ? $data_setting_email['setfrom_smtp'] : null;
// HEADER SETTING
$setting_header = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `setting_header` WHERE `id_hs`='1'");
$data_setting_header = mysqli_fetch_assoc($setting_header);
$logo = $data_setting_header['logo'];
$favicon = $data_setting_header['favicon'];
$title_name = $data_setting_header['title_name'];
$slogan = $data_setting_header['slogan'];
$meta_description = $data_setting_header['meta_description'];
$meta_keyword = $data_setting_header['meta_keyword'];
$google_verification = $data_setting_header['google_verification'];
$bing_verification = $data_setting_header['bing_verification'];
$ahrefs_verification = $data_setting_header['ahrefs_verification'];
$yandex_verification = $data_setting_header['yandex_verification'];
$norton_verification = $data_setting_header['norton_verification'];
// API KEY SETTING
$setting_apikey = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `setting_apikey` WHERE `id_apikey`='1'");
$data_setting_apikey = mysqli_fetch_assoc($setting_apikey);
$google_client_id = $data_setting_apikey['google_client_id'];
$google_client_secret = $data_setting_apikey['google_client_secret'];
$midtrans_client_key = $data_setting_apikey['midtrans_client_key'];
$midtrans_server_key = $data_setting_apikey['midtrans_server_key'];
$rajaongkir_key = $data_setting_apikey['rajaongkir_key'];
$tinypng_key = $data_setting_apikey['tinypng_key'];
// LOKASI TOKO
$lokasi_toko = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `setting_lokasi` WHERE `id`='1'");
$data_lokasi_toko = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lokasi_toko);
$provinsi_toko = $data_lokasi_toko['provinsi'];
$provinsi_id_toko = $data_lokasi_toko['provinsi_id'];
$kota_toko = $data_lokasi_toko['kota'];
$kota_id_toko = $data_lokasi_toko['kota_id'];
// TIPE PEMBAYARAN
$tipe_pembayaran = $server - > query("SELECT * FROM `setting_pembayaran` WHERE `status`='active'");
$data_tipe_pembayaran = mysqli_fetch_array($tipe_pembayaran);
$nama_tipe_pembayaran = $data_tipe_pembayaran['tipe'];

$jumlahPesanan = array(
  'Belum Bayar' => 0,
  'Dikemas' => 0,
  'Dikirim' => 0,
  'Selesai' => 0,
  'Dibatalkan' => 0,
);

// Loop melalui tiap tipe progress dan hitung jumlah pesanan
foreach($jumlahPesanan as $tipeProgress => & $jumlah) {
    // Gunakan prepared statement untuk keamanan
    $query = $server - > prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS jumlah
      FROM invoice INNER JOIN iklan ON invoice.id_iklan = iklan.id INNER JOIN akun ON iklan.user_id = akun.id WHERE(iklan.user_id = ? OR akun.id = ? ) AND invoice.tipe_progress = ? ");
      $query - > bind_param("iis", $iduser, $iduser, $tipeProgress); $query - > execute(); $result = $query - > get_result();

      // Hitung jumlah pesanan
      $row = $result - > fetch_assoc(); $jumlah = $row['jumlah'];

      // Tutup prepared statement
      $query - > close();
    }

    // Fungsi untuk mendapatkan jumlah tipe progress dari database
    function getJumlahTipeProgress($server) {
      $jumlahTipeProgress = array();
      $query = $server - > prepare("SELECT `tipe_progress`, COUNT(*) AS jumlah FROM `invoice` GROUP BY `tipe_progress`");
      $query - > execute();
      $result = $query - > get_result();

      while ($row = $result - > fetch_assoc()) {
        $tipeProgress = $row['tipe_progress'];
        $jumlah = $row['jumlah'];
        $jumlahTipeProgress[$tipeProgress] = $jumlah;
      }

      $query - > close();
      return $jumlahTipeProgress;
    }

    // Dapatkan jumlah tipe progress
    $jumlahTipeProgress = getJumlahTipeProgress($server);

    // Array untuk menyimpan jumlah pesanan berdasarkan tipe progress
    $jumlahPesananTerbaru = array(
      'Belum Bayar' => 0,
      'Dikemas' => 0,
      'Dikirim' => 0,
      'Selesai' => 0,
      'Dibatalkan' => 0,
    );

    // Loop melalui tiap tipe progress dan hitung jumlah pesanan
    foreach($jumlahPesananTerbaru as $tipeProgressTerbaruKey => & $jumlahPesananTerbaruValue) {
      // Gunakan prepared statement untuk keamanan
      $queryPesanan = $server - > prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS jumlah FROM `invoice` WHERE `id_user` = ? AND `tipe_progress` = ?");
      $queryPesanan - > bind_param("is", $iduser, $tipeProgressTerbaruKey);
      $queryPesanan - > execute();
      // Dapatkan hasil query
      $resultPesanan = $queryPesanan - > get_result();
      // Hitung jumlah pesanan
      $rowPesanan = $resultPesanan - > fetch_assoc();
      $jumlahPesananTerbaruValue = $rowPesanan['jumlah'];
      // Tutup prepared statement
      $queryPesanan - > close();
    }

    // Fungsi untuk mendapatkan jumlah tipe progress dari database
    function getJumlahTipeProgressTerbaru($server) {
      $jumlahTipeProgressTerbaru = array();
      $query = $server - > prepare("SELECT `tipe_progress`, COUNT(*) AS jumlah FROM `invoice` GROUP BY `tipe_progress`");
      $query - > execute();
      $result = $query - > get_result();
      while ($row = $result - > fetch_assoc()) {
        $tipeProgressTerbaru = $row['tipe_progress'];
        $jumlah = $row['jumlah'];
        $jumlahTipeProgressTerbaru[$tipeProgressTerbaru] = $jumlah;
      }
      $query - > close();
      return $jumlahTipeProgressTerbaru;
    }

    // Dapatkan jumlah tipe progress
    $jumlahTipeProgressTerbaru = getJumlahTipeProgressTerbaru($server);
```

Comment: How, just **HOW**, would anyone be able  to answer this question without seeing your (PHP-)code ?

Comment: Or you could just create the table referenced in the error message...

Comment: sorry I forgot, I have added the config.php code above

Comment: Use a MySQL query tool to connect to the database this PHP script is using. Run this query: `SHOW TABLES FROM kopsis;`. Does the table `akun` appear in the list?

Comment: It turns out, when I imported the SQL database, there was one table that couldn't be imported, and I imported it manually via a query for that table, it also couldn't, it said JSON or NULL couldn't be the default value. I found an article that MySQL 5 is not supported, I have to upgrade to 8. I will try upgrading MySQL first